# NavigationDrawer is not working

Tags: android, layout, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have read the documentation for NavigationDrawer and tried to create it in my own application. But there is a trouble: the ListView that should be used as menu just floats over the main content and I can't perform any actions with it (e.g. close by swipe). What is the problem?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainPageLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mainScreenViewPager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navigationDrawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:gravity="start" >
</ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the drawer initialization:

```
String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lists_titles);
    ListView drawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);
    drawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
    drawer.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting the navigationDrawer ListView inside the LinearLayout after the FrameLayout?

Comment: That `FrameLayout` is rather odd in the first place. I have no idea why that's there. All it does is make your application slower for no obvious value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough sample of codes that work for me, they're a combination of things from [android developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [StylingAndroid blog](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1793):

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layoutxml_id);

    // must initialize mDrawerLayout and mDrawerToggle in main thread
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // do something
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // do something
        }
    };

    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lists_titles);
    ListView drawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);
    drawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
    drawer.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```