# Android - Navigation Drawer - OnItemClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer

i have a problem with the Navigation Drawer in my app. I cant get the "OnItemClick" - Event of the row items in my drawerlist.

My app contains a Actionbar with some tabs. So my Activity extends from "ActionBarActivity".

Here is my code. I hope someone could help me.

```
public class Hauptmenue_extended extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener,
        android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hauptmenue_extended);

        try {

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(this,
                    getSupportFragmentManager()));

            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Bereitet die ActionBar auf den Navigation Drawer vor
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragView);

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                    GravityCompat.START);


            drawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.drawerTitles_array);

            drawerSubtitles = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.drawerSubtitles_array);

            drawerIcons = new int[] { R.drawable.icon_buergermeldung,
                    R.drawable.icon_sprechblase,
                    R.drawable.icon_action_settings_dark,
                    R.drawable.icon_user_chat, R.drawable.icon_haus,
                    R.drawable.icon_contact, R.drawable.icon_calendar,
                    R.drawable.icon_search };


            MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this,
                    drawerTitles, drawerSubtitles, drawerIcons);

            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this); 


            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);

            Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
            tabB.setText("Home");
            tabB.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_home);
            tabB.setTabListener(new TabListener<Startmenue_activity>(this,
                    "Start", Startmenue_activity.class));
            actionBar.addTab(tabB);

            Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
            tabA.setText("");
            tabA.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_nachrichten_sel);
            tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<Nachrichten_activity>(this,
                    "Nachrichten", Nachrichten_activity.class));
            actionBar.addTab(tabA);

            Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
            tabC.setText("");
            tabC.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_favoriten);
            tabC.setTabListener(new TabListener<Favoriten_activity>(this,
                    "Favoriten", Favoriten_activity.class));
            actionBar.addTab(tabC);


            this.conEinst = new conEinstellungen(getBaseContext());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // Log.d("adkomm", );
            // HelperClassAlertDialog.zeigeInfoDialog(this, "Error...",
            // ex.getMessage(), "");
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Log.d("app", "OnItemClick Drawer");

}
```

The method "OnItemClick" is never called. :( Everything else works perfectly.

Here is the .XML:

> ```
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/pager"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="top" />
> </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/main"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
> </FrameLayout>
>
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:background="#fff"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:clickable="true"
>     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
> ```

**EDIT:**

My ListItem.xml looks like this:

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/icon"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>     android:contentDescription="Entry-Icon"
>     android:src="@drawable/adkomm_logo" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView_balken_drawer"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="5dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle"
>     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>     android:background="#33B5E5" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/title"
>     style="?spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
>     android:ellipsize="end"
>     android:singleLine="true"
>     android:text="test"
>     android:textColor="#33B5E5"
>     android:textStyle="bold" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/subtitle"
>     style="?spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/title"
>     android:text="tester"
>     android:textSize="13dp" />
> ```

**EDIT:**

Here is my "MenuList_Adapter":

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] mTitle;
    private String[] mSubTitle;
    private int[] mIcon;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Hauptmenue_extended mact;

    public MenuListAdapter(String[] pTitle, String[] pSubtitle, int[] pIcon,
            Hauptmenue_extended act) {
        mTitle = pTitle;
        mSubTitle = pSubtitle;
        mIcon = pIcon;
        this.mact = act;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mact
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        itemView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this.mact);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
        txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);
        imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I guess the problem is, that the Navigation Drawer doenst work with ActionBar Tabs. :(

Comment: do you mean the navDrawer doesnt open? Or you cannot click on items in it?

Comment: I cannot click on items in it. It opens well.

Comment: where is your implementation "MenuListAdapter"?  You have an orphan "OnClick" in 'this' ... that is only half of what you need because your detail view ( each row item in MenuListAdapter ALSO may need to implement the "OnEvent" interface so it will properly delegate to what u have in "this"..

Comment: I've added the "MenuListAdapter". Here i add the caller (Haupmenue_extended) as the "onClickListener".

Comment: The guy in these topic has or had the same problems as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093545/navigationdrawer-is-not-working/20431587#20431587

Comment: I guess the problem is, that the Navigation Drawer doenst work with ActionBar Tabs. :(